# Why do Muslims not share the meat of sacrifice with non-Muslims?

Tags: non-muslim, meat, sacrifice, eid-ul-adha

When I was discussing  the topic of Eid and sacrifice meat with my non-Muslim friend, he asked me this question:

> Why do Muslims not share the meat of sacrifice with non-Muslims?

I cannot give him a clear explanation.  Can someone give me a good solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it impermissible to give qurbani meat to non-Muslims?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49672/is-it-impermissible-to-give-qurbani-meat-to-non-muslims)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you share some meat with him? Who told you that Muslims can't share the meat of sacrifice to their non-Muslim friends? I have never heard of such ruling. The meat that is given to the poor (1/3) must be given to Muslims who are poor but you can share the meat which is part of your share (2/3) with your friend and other non-Muslims. Read the following for more:

> Sahih Al-Bukhari Hadith 7.476: Narrated by Salama bin Al Aqua The
> Prophet (saws) said: (Of the Sacrifice) **eat of it, and feed of it to
> others**, and store of it.
>
> Fiqh-us-Sunnah Fiqh 5.115: A person offering
> a sacrifice may consume, **without any restrictions**, any amount of meat
> he may desire. He may likewise give away, or offer in charity any
> amount he may wish. Some scholars say that one may eat half, and give
> away the other half in charity, while others say that the meat be
> divided into three parts. Of these one may keep a part, distribute a
> part, and give in charity the third part.