# Can we give Zakat to non-muslims?

Tags: non-muslim, zakat

One of my colleagues asked me in Ramadhan. Is there allow to give zakat to non-muslim if he is needy one as other Muslims.

Is there clear mentioned in Quran who can get zakat?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE. Do you mean the zakat/saqah of fitr or zakat in general?

Comment: I mean zakat. 2.5 % of income.

Comment: It is a discussed topic see for example [Is it impermissible to give qurabni meat to non-Muslims?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49672/is-it-impermissible-to-give-qurbani-meat-to-non-muslims/) the mainline is not in general. I've just linked the verse and a part of tafsir on it as the question there is a bit different, but OP made an assumption I wanted to adjust. An answer is nevertheless necessary

Comment: http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/42899 should be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the *general* rule about Zakat is that it can not be given to non-Muslims, as it can only be taken from Muslims and can only be given to Muslims.

> الكفار ولو كانوا أهل ذمة: لا يجوز إعطاؤهم من الزكاة. نقل ابن المنذر الإجماع على ذلك لحديث: إن الله افترض عليهم صدقة تؤخذ من أغنيائهم وترد على فقرائهم
>
> Kuffar be they Dhimmi or otherwise: It is not permitted to give them Zakat. Ibn al-Manzar has narrated consensus on this, and the Hadith is: "*Allah has enjoined on them Sadaqa (i.e. Zakat) to be taken from the rich amongst them and given to the poor amongst them*."
>
> <sup>— [Encyclopedia of Islamic Jurisprudence (الموسوعة الفقهية)](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/14390#p1)</sup>

> أن يكون مستحق الزكاة مسلما ً... فلا يجوز صرف الزكاة إلى الكافر بلا خلاف
>
> The one who receives Zakat should be a Muslim ... it is not valid to give Zakat to a Kafir and there is no disagreement on this
>
> <sup>— [Islamic Jurisprudence and its Proofs (الفقه الإسلامي وأدلته)](https://shamela.ws/book/384/1899)</sup>

> المالكية قالوا: ... ويشترط في أخذه منها أن يكون حراً مسلماً
>
> [[Maliki](https://shamela.ws/book/9849/562#p1)] ... There are three conditions for the poor and the needy to be qualified to receive zakah: They must be free, They Must be Muslim ...
>
> الحنابلة قالوا:  ... ولا يجوز دفع الزكاة للكافر
>
> [[Hanbali](https://shamela.ws/book/9849/563#p1)] ... It is not permissible to give Zakah to a Kafir
>
> الشافعية قالوا: ...  ويشترط في أخذ الزكاة من هذه الأصناف الثمانية زيادة على الشروط الخاصة لكل صنف شروط خمسة: الأول: الإسلام؛
>
> [[Shafi](https://shamela.ws/book/9849/564#p1)] ... In order for Zakah to be given to these, the following five conditions must be fulfilled: First, they must be Muslims
>
> <sup>— [Islamic Jurisprudence According To The Four Schools (الفقه على المذاهب الأربعة)](https://archive.org/details/IslamicJurisprudenceAccordingToTheFourSunniSchoolsAlFiqhalaAlMadhahibAlArbaah/page/n869)</sup>

The evidence for this is the Ijma (consensus) on the matter, and the Hadith of the Prophet ﷺ:

> إن الله افترض عليهم صدقة تؤخذ من أغنيائهم وترد على **فقرائهم**
>
> Allah has enjoined on them Sadaqa (i.e. Zakat) to be taken from the rich amongst them and given to the poor **amongst them**
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Bukhari , كتاب المغازى](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/374)</sup>

An exception that is sometimes cited is:

> ... إنما الصدقات ... والمؤلفة قلوبهم
>
> Zakah expenditures are only for ... and for bringing hearts together ...
>
> <sup>— [Quran 9:60](http://quran.com/9/60)</sup>

There is disagreement on exactly who these are, whether they are certain non-Muslims or new converts, and whether their share is abrogated etc. Going into details about this is probably too broad and off-topic for this question, and a cautionary approach would be to avoid areas of disagreement.

You may give other non-obligatory charity (Sadaqah) to help your colleague.